# Return items of a list in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I have to write a program in Lisp that returns the first item of a list if it contains an even number of elements, and the last if it contains an odd number of elements. I need a little advice on where to start? I don't need whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the length of a list with [`length`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_length.htm).

```
(length '(a b c)) ;; 3
```

You can then go and check that number against the predicate function [`evenp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_evenpc.htm), which returns `T` or `NIL` depending on if the argument is even or not.

```
(evenp 1) ;; NIL
(evenp 2) ;; T
```

The function `first` returns the first element of a list.

```
(first '(a b c)) ;; A
```

The function [`last`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_last.htm) returns the last cons of a list, so you'll have to unwrap the value using `FIRST`.

```
(last '(a b c)) ;; (C)
(first (last '(a b c))) ;; C
```

You could then combine these into a function like so:

```
(defun get-first-if-even-length (list)
  (if (evenp (length list))
      (first list)
    (first (last list))))
```

This function returns the first or the last element in the list, depending if its length is even or not.

Comment: thanks! but how can we change the program to return the last item of a list if it contains an odd number of elements?

Comment: I edited the answer. You can use `if` instead of `when` to get an "else" clause. You can then use `last` to access the last element of a list.

Comment: Find out what LAST really does. Not what you assume. Also use FIRST, not CAR.